# ssl virtual host issue on EC2 LAMP

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I am having issues with `SSL` and `virtual hosts` on my `EC2` `LAMP` instance
My virtual host prevents `service httpd start` to work, im getting `[FAILED]` without any clues as to why.
I have a `ssl.conf` present in my `conf.d` folder.
I dont seem to see any error logs inside `/var/log/httpd`
Also `ssl_engine.log` is empty

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName app.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/app.mydomain.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/app_mydomain_com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.ca.crt
        ErrorLog /var/log/ssl_engine.log
</VirtualHost>
```

are there any test i can perform to better understand where the error might be coming from?

Im finding out that when i get rid of `ssl.conf` and any virtual domain with `<VirtualHost *:443>` apache will start, other wise nothing happens and i cant seem to find any error logs.

**update:**
i took this out of `ssl.conf` and apache will now start.
working backwards to see how this is creating an error

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
                     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
                        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

**finally got an error** 
`SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch`

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Apache error logs?

Comment: @MikeBrant i added `ErrorLog /var/log/ssl_engine.log` to my VH but because apache doesnt even start im not getting anything

Comment: Are you seeing anything in syslog?

Comment: @MikeBrant nothing in syslog.  im finding out that `ssl.conf` is stopping apache from starting

Comment: You probably want to add you linux OS information to this question.

Comment: Apache is checking that your certificate contains the public key  compliment to your specified private key, and finding that they don't match. Are you sure you have the correct key and corresponding certificate in place?

Comment: @EliHeady it was strange because i used the exact same credentials to make the key 2nd time around but the output was different.  I was lucky to have an old one around and used that